# insert to different tables batche in one loop

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, batch-processing

I'm parsing a JSON file that keep the user information. I get information one by one and build some classes such as User, UserSettings. Now all this information should be inserted into database.

The JSON file is too big, can have more that 500000 users.

To insert for example User class information I use the following code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (name, city, phone) values (?,?,?)";
Connection conn = getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

final int batchSize = 500;
int count = 0;

User user;
UserSettings userSettings;


for (loop JSON file here and get user info one by one) 
{
     user = parseUser();
     userSettings = parseUserSettings();
     ps.setSting(1,user.getName());
     ps.setString(2,user.getCity());
     ps.setString(3,user.getPhone());
     ps.addBatch();

     if(++count % batchSize == 0)
        ps.executeBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
ps.close();
conn.close();
```

Now in same loop I want to have a batch insert to another table UserSettings. Since I don't want to loop twice the JSON in order to get the UserSettings information. Please provide some solutions !

I think to have for each table a separate thread in same loop. In each thread I'll have his batch. Not sure if that will work and maybe there are some another solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an another `PreparedStatement` for the `INSERT INTO USERSETTINGS` and call `addBatch` / `executeBatch` for that one within the same loop.

If this is an offline / one-time operation, you might have more alternatives (vendor-specific loader tools), but this depends on your RDBMS.

Comment: this should be executed daily, database is MySQL. I need call an API that return a JSON file. each day I need parse it and load data into database